# flow error when accessing maybe type in function expression defined after truthy check

Tags: javascript, flowtype

flow 0.74.0

The code is available on flow's web-based REPL [here](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQUrABYEsA7AcwC4oBnYAJyOIwF8BuDDAMwFdCBjYfAe0JQAhgDEu3ABTDeAwuTiJIASjRRugivwA2EAHTb+xSQHIiI8TxMAaEbMF68dZUwZQW7CX0EjC-PBDUktzC2toARjIA1uSSylDIAHyUNM7o6po6+obGZkLCfgHUNuqhEdFxLsysnDzeQgEwEHj8ACaSAQCC1GRQAPyKSPGY2PhsUJIAhF098dTNHNSELNhYFhIduBDdxC5rawD0B1BshgDuUK38EBSEJsAZALZg2sLmwuH8HA9OFGsahC0ugMRlM5kazVwbRKM2IjgIJD2h2Op34FyuNzuD20+Ci0Bk3BuFDoOC2O3hJPBBAoImo1DRJy8cjWBX8WyCcQSyVhFMRLAYQA)

Flow flags an error on the following statement inside the `theMethod` function: `another(() => theArg.thing)`:

> Cannot get `theArg.thing` because property `thing` is missing in null or undefined

Code:

```
type MyType = {
  thing: string
};

function aFunc(action: MyType){ console.log('in aFunc', action.thing);} ;

function another(callback: () => string) { console.log('in another', callback());};

function theMethod(theArg: ?MyType) {
  if (!theArg) return;

  aFunc(theArg);

  // flow doesn't complain about this
  console.log('in theMethod', theArg.thing);

  // flow doesn't like accessing theArg.thing in this arrow function
  another(() => theArg.thing);
}
```

While `theArg` is typed as maybe, `theMethod` doesn't access `theArg` until after a truthy check is passed.

#### Invalidating Refinement?

The error doesn't appear to be the result of flow [invalidating type refinement](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#toc-refinement-invalidations) due to some method call potentially impacting `theArg` after the truthy check.

Flow isn't complaining that `theArg.thing` could be null/undefined, it is complaining that `theArg` could be null/undefined after the truthy check.  While an outside function can mutate the object that `theArg` references, it cannot change what object `theArg` references.

I double checked this expectation by directly accessing `theArg` in the `theMethod` function body: `console.log('in theMethod', theArg.thing);` after calling a separate function (`aFunc`).  Flow is ok with that.

#### Hoisting?

Flow only complains when i access `theArg` inside of a function expression in `theMethod`, which makes me think that it could be related to hoisting.

My JS foo isn't super strong, but I don't think that is relevant in this case. The arrow function is considered a functional expression and not a declaration, so it wouldn't be hoisted. I also confirmed the behavior is the same if i used an es5 style function expression instead of an arrow function.

So what gives?  Am i missing some flow refinement rule, misunderstanding JS, or is Flow wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Flow doesn't know when `another` will call its callback , so it can't be sure that `theArg` hasn't become null by the time that callback is run. One way to get around this is to take `thing` out of `theArg` and return `thing` from the callback instead. This way, the non-null `thing` is bound in the scope of the callback:

([Try](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQUrABYEsA7AcwC4oBnYAJyOIwF8BuDDAMwFdCBjYfAe0JQAhgDEu3ABTDeAwuTiJIASjRRugivwA2EAHTb+xSQHIiI8TxMAaEbMF68dZUwZQW7CX0EjC-PBDUktzC2toARjIA1uSSylDIAHyUNM7o6po6+obGZkLCfgHUNuqhEdFxLsysnDzeQgEwEHj8ACaSAQCC1GRQAPyKSPGY2PhsUJIAhF098dTNHNSELNhYFhIduBDdxC5rawD0B1BshgDuUK38EBSEJsAZALZg2sLmwuH8HA9OFGsahC0ugMRlM5kazVwbRKM2IjgIJD2h2OADl+BdTuioFE-GcKDgEcQoPhbvcoIQOGF-poHmgnCQ3KhYWsCv4tkE4glkvTdiwGEA))

```
type MyType = {
  thing: string
};

function aFunc(action: MyType){ console.log('in aFunc', action.thing);} ;

function another(callback: () => string) { console.log('in another', callback());};

function theMethod(theArg: ?MyType) {
  if (!theArg) return;

  aFunc(theArg);

  // flow doesn't complain about this
  console.log('in theMethod', theArg.thing);

  // Now flow knows thing isn't null
  const {thing} = theArg
  another(() => thing);
}
```

Comment: James, that makes sense. Flow is making a conservative/defensive assessment because `another` could end up calling that arrow function whenever.  Every time i think i have gotten used to the callback centric nature of JS, it bites in the ass once more. Thanks!